# Why does adding an element to a specific subarray affects all subarrays of given array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Here is my code:

```
but = Array.new(2, []) # => [[], []]
but[1] << 1
but # => [[1], [1]]
```

If I create an array using this:

```
but = [[], []]
```

then the problem does not occur. However, the quantity of subarrays I need to include into `but` is not a stable variable, and alternatives I know to `Array.new`, loops etc., are cumbersome.

Why does this happen? Doesn't `but[1] << 1` affect only one specific sub-element?

Comment: What do you mean by "the problem does not occur"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first sub-array and the second sub-array in `but` are an identical array object. Affecting the second sub-array entails that the first sub-array is also affected.

Note that arguments are evaluated prior to the method they are passed to. In `Array.new(2, [])`, the sub-array `[]` is evaluated to a single array object, then that identical array object is used twice in the newly created array.